# React.js how to send array to react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an array like this :

```
const types = [
        {
            name: 'Catalog A',
            slug: 'catalog-a'
        },
        {
            name: 'Catalog B',
            slug: 'catalog-b'
        },
        {
            name: 'Catalog C',
            slug: 'catalog-c'
        },
        {
            name: 'Catalog D',
            slug: 'catalog-d'
        },
    ]
```

this array is mapped and made into buttons or Links for react-router... the Links works, but not my problem is that I want to pass these array to the components that have no connection from the above components.

here is the mapped button :

```
{types.map(type => (
                        <ButtonToggle
                        key={type}
                        active={active === type}
                        onClick={() => setActive(type)} 
                        show={parseFloat(show)}
                        >
                        <Link to={type.slug} >
                            {type.name}
                            <p>
                                Unpublished
                            </p>
                        </Link>

                        </ButtonToggle>
                    ))}
```

here is what I have in mind for mapping the route :

```
        {types.map(type => (
                        <Route 
                        path={type.slug}
                        >
                          <h1>{type.name}</h1>
                        </Route>
        ))}
```

but now types array must be sent to the above code/components...
I am done with the array, I just make a separate file for it, but i the active state is not done yet.

`active={active === type}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```js
<Link to={{ pathname: type.slug, state: someData }} >
```

then in your next location (`type.slug` I suppose) you should have access like this:

```js
this.props.location.state
```

Comment: so i change this ```<Link to={type.slug} >``` to ```<Link to={{ pathname: type.slug, state: someData }} >```